# I am trying to connect the PS3 controller with the Arduino Uno using a USB Host Shield. Getting stuck at 'PS3 Bluetooth Library Started'

Tags: bluetooth, shields

I did the research for similar issues and found that I had to enable debug. I did the following attempts:

Changes to settings.h - enabled debugging by change from 0 to 1

Getting the following compiling error:

```
/Users/BAGHEL/Documents/Arduino/libraries/USB_Host_Shield_2.0-master/usbh_midi.cpp: In member function 'void USBH_MIDI::parseConfigDescr(byte, byte)':
/Users/BAGHEL/Documents/Arduino/libraries/USB_Host_Shield_2.0-master/usbh_midi.cpp:298:63: error: 'PrintEndpointDescriptor' was not declared in this scope
                                 PrintEndpointDescriptor(epDesc);
                                                               ^
/Users/BAGHEL/Documents/Arduino/libraries/USB_Host_Shield_2.0-master/usbh_midi.cpp: At global scope:
/Users/BAGHEL/Documents/Arduino/libraries/USB_Host_Shield_2.0-master/usbh_midi.cpp:421:80: error: no 'void USBH_MIDI::PrintEndpointDescriptor(const USB_ENDPOINT_DESCRIPTOR*)' member function declared in class 'USBH_MIDI'
 void USBH_MIDI::PrintEndpointDescriptor( const USB_ENDPOINT_DESCRIPTOR* ep_ptr )
                                                                                ^
exit status 1
Error compiling for board Arduino/Genuino Uno.
```

Answer (score -1):

At the risk of stating the bleeding obvious you need to define "PrintEndpointDescriptor()".  I'm sorry but I can't give you a definitive answer to your problem, only generic steps that should solve it.

This almost certainly means you have either missed a include file out or there is a pre-processor flag that is disabling or maybe not enabling that bit of code.

Search through the files in the library and see if there are any pre-processor flags that affect compilation and if so this function.  Have a search on Google for the filename and function name, see that others say.

Another possible solution is look for a readme in the library, or comments in the files that say you need another library including first.  In fact if you are including multiple libraries try changing the order of inclusion.

One last cause could be that the function is within a namespace.  This means you either need to fully qualify the function call (namespace::class::function), or use the horrible using command.